Why is seq function output not consistent?
I am using seq function. While it gives correct output for positive numbers when used input is given using :, I am not sure why does the following 2 ways produce different outputs (when input starts with negative integer in : format):
> seq(-1,1)
[1] -1  0  1

> seq(-1:1)
[1] 1 2 3

I was expecting the same output.

It is documented and discussed on SO.


You don't need seq, it's redundant; 2) The call seq(from) creates the sequence 1, 2, ..., n where n is the length of from. See help("seq"), section Details, fifth form; 3) seq and sequence are not the same, they are very different functions.


identical(seq(-1,1), -1:1). See help(":").

Simply put, in 1st example you are supplying 2 arguments, in the 2nd example only 1. Function behaves differently based on number of arguments. Read the manuals.

@Friede I agree this is very likely a duplicate, but it'd be nice to add a link to duplicate questions, instead of just saying "it has already been asked here".

Thank you, @Maël. I will improve on that.

-1:1 already is a sequence, three numbers long (-1, 0, and 1).  As @Rui Barradas notes on his comment, supplying a single unnamed argument of length > 1 to seq will yield an integer sequence of the same length.  From the "Details" section of seq's documentation:

Typical usages are
seq(from, to)
seq(from, to, by= )
seq(from, to, length.out= )
seq(along.with= )
seq(from)
seq(length.out= )

(...)
The fifth form generates the sequence ‘1, 2, ..., length(from)’ (as if argument ‘along.with’ had been specified).

So, since -1:1 is a vector with three elements, you get the sequence 1, 2, and 3.
